# Is there any way to unsubscribe notification from a particular organization in github enterprise?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I was part of an organization and collaborator for some repositories in that organization, though I was removed from collaborators I get notified for any comment on issue or pull requests , I can mute notification for a particular thread but if a new thread is started I get notified again , so is there any way to unsubscribe notification for a particular organization .

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page when I had a similar problem. Check to see if it helps:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/subscribing-to-and-unsubscribing-from-notifications

Comment: Surya thanks for the reply, but this notification is for a single thread of a repository, i want this functionality for a particular org